# arpriori arules error in R

Tags: r, arules

I am using the arules package in R (3.4.0) to add association rule mining. I have given a simplified version of the code below:

```
library(arules)
data <- paste("trans1 apple", "trans2 apple","trans2 orange","trans3     apple","trans3 orange","trans3 banana", sep ="\n")
write(data, file = "demo_single_1")
tr <- read.transactions("demo_single_1", format = "single", cols = c(1,2))
basket_rules <- apriori(tr,parameter = list(sup = 0.01, conf = 0.01,target="rules"))
```

The apriori command throws the following error:

```
Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen
   0.01    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5    0.01      1
 maxlen target   ext
 10  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 0 

Error in apriori(tr, parameter = list(sup = 0.01, conf = 0.01, target = "rules")) : 
  object 'R_rapriori' not found
```

There is no error while loading the package.

Could someone guide me on how to address this error?

Comment: I can't see any r object as "R_rapriori"

Answer (score 1):

I am getting this as an output if I run your code:

```
Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen maxlen
       0.01    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5    0.01      1     10
 target   ext
  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 0 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[3 item(s), 3 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
sorting and recoding items ... [3 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 2 3 done [0.00s].
writing ... [12 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
```

With no errors to it.

Comment: I have no clue what happened...the same command worked fine after restarting my laptop